# Java application renders Unicode characters well in eclipse, but not when exported as a runnable jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode, jar

I have created a Java application(exported as a jar file) that shows some UTF-8 characters.

The problem is, when we run it in the eclipse, it shows the characters alright. However, when we export it as a runnable jar file and execute it, the characters are jagged.

What could be the reason? I guess some compile settings are not set properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you printing such characteres where, in a console?

Comment: @Claudio Thanks for your reply, Claudio. No, I use java swing object JEditorPane for showing some Chinese characters.

Comment: Are your characters ASCII-escaped ("\u" followed by a number) or have you just put them directly into the String literals?

Comment: @Pawel They're directly put. Actually my application is an email client, and the JEditorPane shows some HTML content(email content) using HTMLEditorKit.

Answer (score 0):

Write your characters into the UTF-8 encoded text file.
There is a tool called `native2ascii` inside of the `[JDK]/bin` folder, use it as follows:

```
native2ascii -encoding utf8 input.txt output.txt
```

Copy the conversion result back into the application's code.

BTW. It is a good idea to externalize this kind of resources.

Comment: Thanks Pawel for your reply. However, I'm putting the Unicode characters from the inbox email content dynamically when running, not statically in compile time. So how can I handle this?

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood you. Try to use ApacheCommons [StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String)) on the String read from the source. OR if there is some kind of string<->byte[] conversion ensure the UTF-8 encoding is explicitly specified.

Comment: Thanks again for your advice Pawel. Well, I tried the `StringEscapeUtils`, but no luck yet. Instead of showing the characters right, it's funny, it rather shows the character like `"\u517C"`. I don't know if you might have used HTMLEditorKit. FYI it shows html content as if the JEditorPane(that it is applied to) is an html viewer or something. So, all tags apply. I'm thinking that I might have to change the `charset=UTF-8` setting from the `meta` tag.

Comment: OK, i've used this tool in the past in a little bit different situation, so no guarantees it will solve your problem.  BTW You might want to use complimentary "unescapeJava" method to return the string  (in its original form) to the output.

Comment: Sorry, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, when we run it in the eclipse, it shows the characters alright. However, when we export it as a runnable jar file and execute it, the characters are jagged.

I'm assuming that when you say "jagged", you are using that word with its normal English meaning; i.e. the displayed characters are recognizable, but the rendering is rough and ugly.

If that is the case, then the problem is with the font that is being to render the characters.  That is typically determined by the "look and feel" (I think) if your UI is rendered by Swing ... or the console program if you are writing to a console.

> I guess some compile settings are not set properly.

I doubt that it has anything to do with compiler settings.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your response. First, I meant the characters were not shown properly by "jagged", like some strange-looking characters. Second, I'm using "Arial Unicode MS" as the selected font.